# Doing linear prediction with R: How to access the predicted parameter(s)?

Tags: r, linear-regression, predict

I am new to `R` and I am trying to do linear prediction. Here is some simple data:

```
test.frame<-data.frame(year=8:11, value= c(12050,15292,23907,33991))
```

Say if I want to predict the value for `year=12`. This is what I am doing (experimenting with different commands):

```
lma=lm(test.frame$value~test.frame$year)  # let's get a linear fit
summary(lma)                              # let's see some parameters
attributes(lma)                           # let's see what parameters we can call
lma$coefficients                          # I get the intercept and gradient
predict(lm(test.frame$value~test.frame$year))  
newyear <- 12                             # new value for year
predict.lm(lma, newyear)                  # predicted value for the new year
```

Some queries:

1. if I issue the command `lma$coefficients` for instance, a vector of two values is returned to me. How to pick only the intercept value?
2. I get lots of output with `predict.lm(lma, newyear)`  but cannot understand where the predicted value is. Can someone please clarify?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: I've updated my answers to give correct answers with the variable names of your question

Comment: Also, `lm(value ~ year, data=test.frame)` is a more readable way to specify the model, which I got pretty excited about when first learning some R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

intercept:

```
lma$coefficients[1]
```

Predict, try this:

```
test.frame <- data.frame(year=12, value=0)
predict.lm(lma, test.frame)
```